# Google Scripts - removeEditors() on multiple protections

Tags: google-apps-script

I am having difficulties in solving a timeout error for a script for Google Sheets that used to work fine in the past.

In brief - I have a spreadsheet with 12 different tabs (sheets). Every day a script protects the whole 12 sheets and then unprotects specific (different) ranges from them, thus effectively creating 12 different protection objects - one per every sheet.

At the end of the script I am executing the following:

```
protection1.addEditor(me);
protection2.addEditor(me);
protection3.addEditor(me);
protection4.addEditor(me);
protection5.addEditor(me);
protection6.addEditor(me);
protection7.addEditor(me);
protection8.addEditor(me);
protection9.addEditor(me);
protection10.addEditor(me);
protection11.addEditor(me);
protection12.addEditor(me);
protection1.removeEditors(protection1.getEditors());
protection2.removeEditors(protection2.getEditors());
protection3.removeEditors(protection3.getEditors());
protection4.removeEditors(protection4.getEditors());
protection5.removeEditors(protection5.getEditors());
protection6.removeEditors(protection6.getEditors());
protection7.removeEditors(protection7.getEditors());
protection8.removeEditors(protection8.getEditors());
protection9.removeEditors(protection9.getEditors());
protection10.removeEditors(protection10.getEditors());
protection11.removeEditors(protection11.getEditors());
protection12.removeEditors(protection12.getEditors());
```

This ugly approach used to work fine for years, but at one point it started sporadically to time out, until the moment where it never managed to finish on time again.

Now I am looking for a solution which will allow to perform the addEditor / removeEditors on all protections simultaneously, which should resolve my timeout problem.

Thank you very much for any hints that you might give me!

Comment: The hint is to use Protection.setRange() method instead of .addEditor() / .removeEditors(). This may be more efficient to replace protected range for the same editors set. I have no experience with so specific task, but you can simply try this way.

Comment: I followed your approach - now I am not removing the protections in order to create them again, but I am just redefining them with the old list of editors. Now my script executes in 7 seconds instead of timing out.
Many thanks @АлександрЕрмолин !